# Selenium Webdriver together with SSM?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, sap-solution-manager

Can someone tell me if Selenium WebDriver can be used by SAP Solution Manager?
I can't find anything about this issue on the internet.

Comment: what do you want with SAP solution Manage? Please elaborate more

Comment: I want to use SSM as a testmanagement tool and Selenium Webdriver as automation tool for testing SAP CRM. Is that possible?

Comment: Is it possible to start Selenium Webdriver scripts from SSM? So can SSM and Selenium Webdriver collaborate with eachother?